# jquery solution to replace an img link with new image and link

Tags: jquery

Current HTML

```
<td rowspan="3" class="brandlogo">
<a href="http://www.myfantasyleague.com/">
<img src="http://www5.myfantasyleague.com/images/new_mfl_logo.png" alt="http://www.myfantasyleague.com/" border="0" height="80" width="80">
</a>
</td>
```

I need to use jquery to replace so the output would be

```
<td rowspan="3" class="brandlogo">
<a href="newurl">
<img src="newimagesource" alt="" border="0" height="80" width="80">
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: and where's *your* input to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var href = "newurl";
var imgPath = "newimagesource";//"newimagesource.jpg"
$('.brandlogo a').attr('href',href);
$('.brandlogo a img').attr('src',imgPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop()` to set new values

```
$("td>a").prop("href", "newurl");
$("td>a>img").prop("src", "newimagesource");
$("td>a>img").prop("alt", "")
```